# What is the `<Rinternals.h>` header, and when is it installed?

Tags: r, c, header, rcpp

I am starting to look at using `.Call` to run `C` code within R
(I am doing this before I start to use Rcpp).

I saw that we need to include the header file `Rinternals.h` at the start of the C program with:

`#include <Rinternals.h>`

I was wondering what this header file is exactly, and when is it installed?
In other words, is this header file part of the `C` compiler or is it installed with R.

Comment: A casual search through your R installation would quickly find the answer to "where": possibly `lib/R/include/Rinternals.h` on linux, `include/Rinternals.h` on windows. If you aren't sure of what that header is, then have you read all of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask R about that:

```
> file.path( R.home("include"), "Rinternals.h" )
[1] "/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h"
>
```

(This reflects that on my system `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/share/` both have an `R` directory, Linux distros may differ here.  They key point is R knows from compile- and build time, and provides the info. Beats hard-coding `/usr/lib` as some `Makefile` version in the wild.)

(In general, there is a ridiculous wealth of tools in base R packages `utils` and `tools`. They are also well written!)

Moreover, you don't even need to know!  If you test `.Call()` by doing

```
R CMD COMPILE myfile.cpp
R CMD SHLIB myfile.o
```

then R will know where to find the headers and library files from.  You are still stuck with having to *explicitly* load the shared library file whose extensions name will differ by operating system.  All this is ... indeed much easier with Rcpp and its helpers `sourceCpp()` or `cppFunction()`.